# Aspect-oriented extension for entities in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, spring-data-mongodb, spring-aop, load-time-weaving

I have a Spring Boot 2.7.6 application. I have some entities that are managed via various Mongo repositories. I would like to extend my entities with metadata. So I thought I'd build a metadata repository that contains the metadata for all entities and extend the entities with an interface `IMetadata` that contains a default implementation. This method should then load the data from the metadata repository using an aspect and then return it.

This is what my classes look like:

```java
package io.zzzz.interfaces;
//imports are there

public interface IMetadata {
  @JsonIgnore
  default List<Metadata> getMetadata() {
    return null;
  }
```

```java
package io.zzzz.entities;
//imports are there

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Configurable
@Document("samples")
public class SampleEntity implements IMetadata {
  @Id private String id;
  // ... many other fields
```

```java
package io.zzzz;
//imports are there

@Aspect
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
@Slf4j
public class MetadataAspect implements ApplicationContextAware {
  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
    metadataService = context.getBean(MetadataService.class);
  }

  @Around("execution(* getMetadata(..))")
  public Object getMetadataAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    log.debug("Accessing metadata ...");
    var metadataOwner = joinPoint.getTarget();
    var md = metadataService.getMetadataForEntity((IMetadata) metadataOwner);
    log.debug("Accessed metadata.");
    return md;
  }
}
```

I have added the following dependencies:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.24</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

I added `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` to my application and also added a javaagent to the VM Options `-javaagent:<path>/spring-instrument-5.3.24.jar`.

Because none of this worked, I created the following `aop.xml` in `META-INF`:

```xml
<aspectj>
  <weaver>
    <include within="io.zzzz.entities..*"/>
  </weaver>
  <aspects>
    <aspect name="io.zzzz.MetadataAspect"/>
  </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

I added the VM option `-Daj.weaving.verbose=true` to extend the logging during startup to see if something happened. I see some weavering, so that should at least basically work. If I formulate the aspect and aop-config a bit more generally, then I also see that, for example, service methods are called and passed through the aspect, but my `getMetadata` method is not.

I don't know what to do. Maybe my idea won't work at all.

Comment: `SampleEntity` does not seem to be a Spring-managed bean/component. Why are you expecting Spring AOP to have any effect on it? Please clarify. Was your goal to use Spring AOP, as the configuration implies, or do you wish to use native AspectJ to intercept non-Spring-managed classes?

Comment: @kriegaex Sorry for the late reply. I had hoped that the `SampleEntity` would be spring-managed by the `@Configurable` annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had hoped that the `SampleEntity` would be spring-managed by the `@Configurable` annotation

No, it is still unmanaged without any `@Component`, `@Service` or similar Spring component annotations. As the name implies, it simply makes an unmanaged object **configurable**, i.e. you can inject Spring beans into it using `@Autowired`. See [this Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-bean-into-unmanaged-objects) and of course the Spring documentation for more information:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/using-aspectj.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html

Please note that you need to activate native Aspect weaving in combination with the `spring-aspects` aspect library in order for `@Configurable` to have any effect via `AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect`.

---

**Update:** I forgot to mention, that if you want to apply AOP to non-managed classes, you have a choice to either make them managed as mentioned before or to use native AspectJ, which has no such Spring-related limitations and can be applied to POJO code, with or without Spring. AspectJ also does not require or create any proxies.